# Spring boot 2 - REST controller test throws exception on org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have a test that's throwing an `Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources]` exception for my Spring boot 2 REST controller class. Am I missing some additional setup here or did I implement the test not correctly?

```
@RestController
public class BiodiversityController {

    private final SpecieService specieService;

    private final SpecieResourceAssembler speciePagedResourcesAssembler;


    public BiodiversityController(SpecieService specieService, SpecieResourceAssembler speciePagedResourcesAssembler) {
        this.specieService = specieService;
        this.speciePagedResourcesAssembler = speciePagedResourcesAssembler;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SpecieResource>> getAllSpecies(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Specie> assembler){
        Page<Specie> species = specieService.getAllSpecies(pageable);
        PagedResources<SpecieResource> specieResources = assembler.toResource(species, speciePagedResourcesAssembler);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(specieResources);
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BiodiversityController.class)
@Import(SpecieResourceAssembler.class)
public class BiodiversityControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private SpecieService specieService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private SpecieResourceAssembler specieResourceAssembler;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new 
        BiodiversityController(specieService, specieResourceAssembler))
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllSpecies_ShouldReturnSpecies() throws Exception {
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 20);
        given(specieService.getAllSpecies(pageRequest)).willReturn(new PageImpl<>(
            Collections.singletonList(createAnimaliaOrestias()), pageRequest, 1));

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/species?page=0&size=20"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content.[0].name").value(NAME_ORESTIAS));

        verify(specieService).getAllSpecies(pageRequest);
    }
```

The stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources]: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
at biodiversity.controller.BiodiversityControllerTest.getAllSpecies_ShouldReturnSpecies(BiodiversityControllerTest.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources]: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.getJaxbContext(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:116)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.createMarshaller(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:50)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:183)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:71)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:226)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:275)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:224)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
... 40 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.getJaxbContext(AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.java:111)
... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0):

user987339 started me thinking and I found the solution to my problem. I added the pageable support first to my rest controller resulting in failing tests in order to solve it i added this dependency

```
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
```

After adding `PagedResources` support in the controller, the added dependency caused this exception, so just removing it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is using maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```